# Is there any way to send a one-time code in firebase to the users email

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have read the functions docs and the authentication codes on the firebase website, but I have no clue if it will be secure or not. I've read the whole of this doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler

They seem to do all the verification on the website but I can't find the verifyPasswordResetCode(actionCode) function in the node.js doc so what way would you go around this?

Basically, if the user forgets their password/needs to verify their email I want the user to go to my website (I've already configured the custom action URL that is sent when the user requests to reset their email to go to 'mywebsite.com/auth/action/.../'. I know that the my front end (IOS App) needs to verify the code and then In my functions (that's hosted on my website) I need to reset their password, but how would I securely transfer information from the email to my app, to my website with the function to reset their password with the action code. Or can I do it all on my website instead of where they input their new password on the website? I'm guessing using dynamic links?

Thanks,

Nathan

Comment: Firebase already includes the one time code in the GET parameter `oobCode`. You would extract it from the query string and use it to verify with Firebase using `auth.verifyPasswordResetCode(oobCode)`. For good UX flow, you can use dynamic link to navigate your user from the password reset web page back to your mobile app.

Comment: @JoshuaChanc could someone told me the auth.verifyPasswordResetCode(oobCode) is not in the node.js function's library and I needed to verify the oobCode on the client side before resetting the password with the confirmPasswordRestCode(oobCode) on the node.js server side. How would I pass the data between them all?

Comment: You can set the action URL to be your backend API and then call [auth.confirmPasswordReset](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.auth.Auth.html#confirmpasswordreset) in the node admin SDK.

Comment: @JoshuaChan this is what confuses me. So the backend API would be the function that I deploy to firebase and the node admin SDK would be run from where? (since apparently that auth.confirmPasswordReset function is only available in the javascript sdk?)

Comment: The backend API could be any node server you're hosting that listens to the action URL that you set, it can also be a cloud function in Firebase. Both [auth.confirmPasswordReset](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.auth.Auth.html#confirmpasswordreset) and [auth.verifyPasswordResetCode](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.auth.Auth.html#verify-password-reset-code) you see here are from the Node Admin Javascript SDK.

Comment: @JoshuaChan Okay, sorry, but where would the NodeJS Admin SDK be put, it can't be put on the same function as it's not supported by the same reference? Would I have to host it in a different place on my website or? As it's referenced as 'Node.js client' not sever.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204039/discussion-between-joshua-chan-and-nathan).